# fabric.js: reset controls axis of group after rotation

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs, coordinate-transformation

Not sure if I have titled this question correctly but I am creating a group from an SVG and need it to look like it is on top of an isometric box. So I need to rotate it by 45 degrees and then scale down it's height.

The problem is that after rotating it, changing the height will still change the groups original (rotated) Y axis.

Here's a visual explanation...

[image]

Here is the relevant code I am using...

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(patternURL, function (svgpattern) {

    var ptnGroup = new fabric.Group(svgpattern, {
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      angle: 45
    });

    ptnGroup.scaleY = .3;
    canvas.add(ptnGroup);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that scaling is applied before rotation. To force scaling to happen after rotation, you can wrap `ptnGroup` in another group and apply the scale to the outer group:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(patternURL, function (svgpattern) {

  var ptnGroup = new fabric.Group(svgpattern, {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    angle: 45
  });

  var scaleGroup = new fabric.Group([ ptnGroup ], {
    scaleY: 0.3
  });
  canvas.add(scaleGroup);
}
```

Alternatively you could use a transformation matrix with the rotation and scaling transformations multiplied in the correct order:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(patternURL, function (svgpattern) {

  var ptnGroup = new fabric.Group(svgpattern, {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 500,
    height: 500
  });

  ptnGroup.transformMatrix = [0.707, 0.212, -0.707, 0.212, 0, 0];
  canvas.add(ptnGroup);
}
```

Here 0.707 comes from `cos(45°)`, and 0.212 is `cos(45°) * 0.3`.

Comment: Wrapping the group with another group worked. Funny thing is that I actually tried this myself before I asked this question but it didn't work because I missed the square brackets around ptnGroup. Thanks Peter.